# Net::SSLeay extract public key

Tags: perl

I need to generate a key pair with Net::SSLeay and send the public key to a central web service.

I managed to generate a RSA pair and extract the private.pem. How can I extract the public key with Net::SSLeay?

```
use Net::SSLeay;
use File::Slurp ;

my $pk = Net::SSLeay::EVP_PKEY_new();
my $rsa = Net::SSLeay::RSA_generate_key(2048, 0x10001);
Net::SSLeay::EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA($pk,$rsa);
my $pem_privkey = Net::SSLeay::PEM_get_string_PrivateKey($pk);

write_file("private.pem", $pem_privkey);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason that you want to use the low-level OpenSSL API? There are other modules that handle those details, such as [Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA):

```
use v5.10;

use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;

$rsa = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->generate_key(1024);

say "private key is:\n", $rsa->get_private_key_string();
say "public key (in PKCS1 format) is:\n",
      $rsa->get_public_key_string();
say "public key (in X509 format) is:\n",
      $rsa->get_public_key_x509_string();
```

Comment: I was hoping to add the Microsoft CAPI to Net::SSLeay to access the Microsoft Key Store. But I am not able to compile Net::SSLeay on Windows, otherwise I would add PEM_get_string_PublicKey.  Also, I need to create a certificate request and Crypt::OpenSSL::PKCS10 fails when I use new_from_rsa in combination with Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA or Crypt::PK::RSA. So I started to stick with Net::SSLeay as it seems to be the best approach for all openssl requirements until now. Only thing I'm missing is exporting the public key.